# replace empty paranthese in a string in java

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I'm caught up in a simple problem.I nees to replace the empty parantheses in a string in java. For example :

```
String str = "aaaa()";
```

needs to be `"aaaa"`.

I tried :

```
str.replaceAll("()", "");
```

but this is not working.

Due to project constraint I have to use jdk1.4

Comment: () is regex type. You should use "\\" before the ()

Answer (score 8):

You have to escape the parenthesis because [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) use regex, and parenthesis is a reserved characters in regex to define groups :

```
str.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");
```

or in your case, you just need use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) :

```
str.replace("()", "");
```